# Tesseract on OSX: dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libtiff.5.dylib

Tags: tesseract

I just installed tesseract locally on my mac and installed Leptonia . Xaamp use as utility server .

I have the following problem , when you launch the command tesseract from terminal all is successful, however, if the launch tesseract command from php script gives me this error :

***dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libtiff.5.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/opt/leptonica/lib/liblept.4.dylib
  Reason: Incompatible library version: liblept.4.dylib requires version 8.0.0 or later, but libtiff.5.dylib provides version 6.0.0***

can someone help me? thank you

Answer (score 5):

I did this and it helped me with a similar problem.
https://sourceforge.net/p/vietocr/discussion/833570/thread/e1eec2b14b/#e296

I went to `/usr/local/opt/tesseract/lib/`. I had `libtesseract.5.dylib` and created a symlink with following command: `sudo ln -s libtesseract.5.dylib libtesseract.4.dylib`

Comment: I was installing PHP 8.1 on OS X and I had the same problem with libavif.16.dylib and libtiff.5.dylib. I created the symbolic links and then PHP installed w/o problems. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: had the same issue!! but in my case  I used the following: `ln -s libtiff.6.dylib libtiff.5.dylib` (path: `/usr/local/opt/libtiff/lib/`)

Answer (score 2):

I have a problem similar, but not the same. You can try this: 
brew install tesseract
If you Could not symlink, /usr/local/bin is not writable, use this  command: 
sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local

After that install the autoconf, automake, and libtool with this command:
brew install autoconf automake libtool

I think you will need use this one as well: brew install leptonica --with-libtiff
Finally use the link command to link all libs: brew link tesseract, brew link automake, brew link libtool, etc...

I hope it helps you.